# How to put a switch in a UITableView

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uiswitch

How do i put a switch in a `TableView`? I have an array set to the `TableView` that has three items and I want to display a switch next to each one. Is this possible? I have tried embedding it in the `TableView` cell but that did nothing at all and I honestly don't know why. Any help is appreciated.

By the way, this is the code I used that did not help:

```
Cell.accessoryView = switchView;
                [switchView setOn:NO animated:NO];
                [switchView addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
                [switchView release];
```

Comment: I would suggest creating a custom UITableViewCell, and then adding your switch to it as a subview (not accessoryView). This way, you can also add other elements to it at a future date, and there would be no problems in your datasource function since you can cast it using (UITableViewCell*).

Answer (score -1):

You can easily do it by putting the switch in `UITableViewCell`. I did it without any problem. I am sharing my cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        StatusCell *cell = (StatusCell*) [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"StatusCell"];
        if (cell == nil) {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"StatusCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }
        cell.name.text = [_StatArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.switchControl.tag = indexPath.row;
        if ([[_StatArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"Seat Allocated"]) {
            NSString *s = [[_StatArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] lowercaseString];
            NSString *ss = [s stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"_"];
            [cell.switchControl setOn:[[self.statusArr objectForKey:ss] boolValue] animated:YES];
        }
        else{
            if ([[_StatArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"Seated"]) {
                [cell.switchControl setOn:[[self.statusArr objectForKey:[[_StatArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] lowercaseString]] boolValue] animated:YES];

            }
            else
            [cell.switchControl setOn:[[self.statusArr objectForKey:[[_StatArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] lowercaseString]] boolValue] animated:YES];
        }
        [cell.switchControl addTarget:self action:@selector(stateSwitched:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        return cell;
}
```

You just have to keep track of each switch state. Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: While down voting please add some comment, so that I know why you didn't like it.

Comment: The comment is too generic, you should give explanations, not to just copy & paste your code here. The man who asked did not mention neither that he uses a .xib file for the custom cell, nor that he uses a prototype cell in a .storyboard. You should ask him first how is creating his cells, otherwise the code you posted may confuse him, and not even closely solve his problem. Plus, he is not using ARC, so your code is error-prone if he will try to reuse it as it is. Also "_StatArr" is according to the coding conventions.